# error al cargar archivo en servidor pyhton con flask

Tags: html, python, formularios, flask

estoy intentando cargar una imagen por un formulario de html usando flask y python.
la imagen pesa 4Mb pero al memento de querer cargar el archivo me vota un error de desconección, sin embargo cuando la imagen pesa menos de 100Kb la sube sin problema ya he revisado varias veces el código y no entiendo que sucede.

estoy en visual estudio code y linux, soy algo nuevo en la programación y he buscado por varios foros pero no encuentro algún error parecido

este es mi código

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    #procesamiento de imágenes
    file = request.files['imagen_Paginas']
    base_path = os.path.dirname (__file__)
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    
    if extension == ".jpg" or extension == ".png" or extension == ".jpeg":
        nuevoNombreFile = stringAleatorio() + extension
        upload_path = os.path.join (base_path, 'static/archives/paginas', nuevoNombreFile) 
        file.save(upload_path)
        #modifico el path
        start = 48
        url_imagen = upload_path[start:]
        
        edit_Imagen = Paginas(request.form['id'], None, None, url_imagen, None, None)
        
        respuesta_Edit_Imagen_Paginas = consultasPaginas.paginas_Editar_imagen(db, edit_Imagen)
        
        if respuesta_Edit_Imagen_Paginas == True:
                flash('Imagen actualizada con éxito...')
                return redirect(url_for('edit_paginas'))
        else:
            os.remove(upload_path)
            flash('Algo salio mal...')
            return redirect(url_for('edit_paginas'))

    else:
        flash("Formato de imagen invalido")
        return redirect(url_for('edit_paginas'))
else:
    return redirect(url_for('edit_paginas'))
```

y este pantalla me sale cuando la imagen pesa mas de 100Kb
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo mas raro es que cuando lo hago ni siquiera entra la función del route, simplemente sale esa pantalla y ya.

Comment: ¿Cómo lanzas tu servidor? ¿Usas el servidor de desarrollo de flask, es decir, el que se lanza con `app.run()`? Ese podría ser el problema

Comment: si, estoy usando ese mismo servidor ejecutado desde visual con la terminal.

Comment: He leido que da ese tipo de problemas al subirle ficheros grandes, y que se resuelve si en vez de usar el servidor de desarrollo usas uno más profesional, como gunicorn. Puedo escribir una respuesta indicando cómo se ejecutaría desde gunicorn